# Bidirectional text and numbers

Tags: html, css, bidi

I have a website that displays in two languages - english and farsi. The title of a list item **can be in both languages mixed at the same time**. All ok until here as far as you have text only it will render ok using `direction:rtl` in css.

But the catch is that **I can also have a number inside or at the end of title** (which in farsi is written and read same as in english - left to right). This ends up with a problem since no matter where I put that number it will mess up the words order in the title (the number is an ad ID at the end of the title).

To solve this issue I use `&rlm` and `&lrm` infront of the id - but the catch is that I have to switch this two according which language is choosen.

[image: Bidirectional text with number problem]

My correct html is as this (`&rlm;` is what fixes the id number issue in farsi):

```
<h3>
   The name of my خدمات باشد is long
   <span style="color:#999;">&rlm;#89798798</span>
</h3>
```

JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/WzF2D/

I tried setting `direction:ltr` on the span wrapping around ID but it still won't work. I also tried to use `unicode-bidi:embed` on `h3` but also no go.

**How can I solve this by using css only without having to rely on `&rlm;`?**

Comment: Deleted my answer as it was wrong -don't want to mislead anyone-

Comment: @orique - np hope someone tackled this problem before - I'll put a bounty on in 2 days if no answer.

Comment: Please provide a real, complete, testable example and explain how the rendering differs from the correct. What you present as correct HTML is correct but has nothing to do with the question asked.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Added JSFiddle for illustration. Check there to see.

Comment: @easwee, I don’t see how the presentation flagged as correct would be correct. English is written left to right. Any embedded text in Arabic writing would internally go right to left, of course.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela The text part is ok - I got that confirmed from the client - that's how they expect it to see like that. The problem is when I add number id at the end - if no `&rlm` is used it will jump in the middle of the title text instead of staying at the end.

Comment: If they expect to see it like that, they should specify the exact rules to be applied, as they would definitely deviate from normal layout and writing rules. Only after defining the rules can one meaningfully discuss the technical implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume that the desired rendering uses overall right-to-left writing, even though the text (at least in the example) is mainly English, with some words in Arabic letters inside the sentence. Moreover, I assume that expressions like “#89798798” are to be treated as separate fragments, so that when it appears after an English word, it is not considered as part of English text but set to the left of it, in RTL layout.

Under these (rather astonishing) premises, the CSS solution is to make such a fragment a bidirectionality isolate:

```
<span style="color:#999; unicode-bidi: embed">#89798798</span>
```

Comment: Rather astonishing but that's what they wanted. Works as intended. Just edited a typo there on missing style. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just one more question - is unicode-bidi somewhat a css alternative instead of using `&lrm` and `&rlm`? Can't really find any relevant information about it.

Comment: @easwee, no, `&lrm;` and `&rlm;` affect the directionality of directionally neutral text, whereas `unicode-bidi: embed` creates an isolate, which could also be created using the HTML5 element `<bdi>` (bidirectionality isolate), but it has not yet been implemented in browsers. Depending on context, the effect may in some cases be the same.

Comment: Thanks, that's some precious info.